# Getting started with github

Tags: android, github, commonsware

I'm going through a book with links telling me to download stuff from github.  for instance look at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39662979/githubShot.png.  for the life of me I can't figure out how to download the contents of that ActionBarSherlock directory.  I'm used to having a "download" button where you just get your stuff by hitting the button.  can someone give me a clue?

I went through the help but it didn't help.

thanks, 
Gary

Comment: Not a perfect title.  Maybe something like "Download single directory from GitHub"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a download button labeled "ZIP" when you're in the root of the project.  That will download *the entire* project.  There's no simple way that I know of to download a *single* directory.

[image: What I see...]

Comment: Thanks.  The book I have implied that there was a way to download just that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Read this help page from GitHub itself on how to fork a repository:

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Following the article will give you a copy of the repository on your local machine.

Alternatively, if you click the "downloads" link in the top right corner (next to Tags 7 in that image), GitHUB will open a doalog and give you the option of downloading the repository as either a zip file or a .tgz (tar + gzip) file.

Hope that helps.